# Core Data fetch request with array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am trying to set a fetch request with a predicate to obtain records in the store whose identifiers attribute match an array of identifiers specified in the predicate e.g.

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"identifier IN %@", employeeIDsArray];
```

The employeeIDsArray contains a number of NSNumber objects that match IDs in the store. However, I get an error "Unable to parse the format string". This type of predicate works if it is used for filtering an array, but as mentioned, fails for a core data fetch. How should I set the predicate please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NSPredicate` doesn't use formats like `NSString` does. So that the result of a predicate creation using the pre-generated predicateString won't be a valid predicate.

You have to make it an actual predicate:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier IN %@", employeeIDsArray];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) for more informations on predicate formats.

Comment: Thanks, but of course I do call: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];

Comment: Apologies for not accepting your answer earlier. I have tried your suggestion and it works.

Answer (score 4):

When you create that string using `stringWithFormat:`, that method inserts the array's *`description`* (a string describing the contents of the array) where you had `%@`.

That's not what you want. You don't want to test membership in a string describing the array; you want to test membership in *the array*. So, don't go through `stringWithFormat:`—pass the format string and the array to `predicateWithFormat:` directly.

Comment: Thank you. Had to give "Answered" to the first poster, but +1 because thanks to you I now understand why.

Comment: +1 for noticing why it wasn't working!  I just thought he had forgotten to turn his string into a predicate.